# Css combining multiple Hover Effects

Tags: css, image, hover, caption

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the div is hovered over the `background-color` fades-in, the rounded image scales in size and a text overlay appears over the image simultaneously.

I'm close to achieving it as I have the `background-color` transition and image scaling working at the same time but I can only get the text overlay to trigger as when I hover over the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Demo in the comments.

Comment: http://codepen.io/caseybr/pen/zqgQdX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your CSS to apply the hover animation when the `.hvr-fade` div is hovered instead of the `.textfade` div.

**From**

```
.textfade:hover {
    opacity:1;
}

.textfade:hover h2 {
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px);
}
```

**To**

```
.hvr-fade:hover .textfade {
    opacity:1;
}

.hvr-fade:hover .textfade h2 {
    -moz-transform: translateY(40px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
    transform: translateY(40px);
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/BKXexm)

Comment: Thanks Hunter. Saved me an hour or 2 of pain :-)